# How to create a thumbnail image in NodeJs using sharp library?

Tags: node.js, image, npm

I am trying to find a suitable library for image processing,
Basically, I have a use-case for `Resizing, Compressing and creating thumbnails` of an image,
I found that `sharp` seems to be a popular node library choice for image processing,

I am able to do some basic operations like resizing an image but,
I couldn't find a way to create thumbnails or smaller sized quality images of the original one.
Can someone please point to the correct code for creating thumbnails and smaller resolution images using the `sharp` library?

**Sample working code:**

```
const sharp = require('sharp');

let test = async () => {

    await sharp('/pathToImage/test.jpg')
    .resize({
        fit: sharp.fit.outside
    })
    .sharpen()
    .toFile('fitOutside.jpg')
    .then(info => { 
        console.log(info);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });

};

test();
```

**Reference -**
http://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/en/stable/api-resize/
https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/en/stable/api-resize/#examples_2

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I don't understand your question. Just resize down to eg. 128 x 128 and save as a jpg. Isn't that a thumbnail?

Comment: I tried to resize by setting the desired dimensions but, it's removing a part of the image. I need a good quality small-sized version of the original HQ image

Comment: I wrote a blog on this https://medium.com/@pprathameshmore/generating-image-thumbnails-using-sharp-library-in-nodejs-7d697cc931fe?source=friends_link&sk=7525a2e32d6b77292b697152648d02d7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you give both width and height, sharp will usually need to either add or remove pixels on one axis. You can control what it does with the `fit` parameter:

http://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/en/stable/api-resize/

The default is `centre`, it sounds like you'd prefer `outside`.

Comment: Updated the question, I just tried using `fit: sharp.fit.outside` without specifying the dimensions, but in this case, it kept the original size? Should I specify the `width` and `height` parameters?

Comment: You have two options: 1. Just give width and it'll resize to that width while letting height float. 2. Give width and height, and specify how you'd like the image to be fitted.

Comment: For case -> 1. I specify the `width` and `fit` correct? and for case 2. I specify the `width`, `height` and `fit: sharp.fit.outside`

Comment: No, you only need `fit` if you give both width and height.

Comment: then `case 2`. is correct yea? for `case 1`. only specify `width`?